# Monoalphabetic Equation

Tags: word, cipher, language, letters

A set of letters has been replaced by $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.
Following are some of the words that consist of those letters, and their meaning:

> $abc = a\ title\ (n.)$
>
> $abcd = a\ title\ > abc\ (n.),\ give\ cbad\ to\ (v.)$
>
> $Dcba ⊂ (a\ title\ > abcd)\ (n.)$
>
> $Dcba = Represents\ what\ often\ comes\ before\ or\ after\ bcd\ (n.)$
>
> $bcd = ARGHH!\ (n.)$
>
> $cbad = move\ abc\ to\ abcd\ (v.),\ \land (v.)$

**What are the letters that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ replace, respectively?**

Comment: When you say alphabets do you mean letters?

Comment: @gabbo1092 Yes, these are English words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a, b, c, d are

> s, i, r, e 
>  
>  "sir" = a title (given to a man)
>  "sire" = a title greater than "sir" (given to a king), or to give "rise" to 
>  "Eris" = Name (names are titles) of someone greater than a "sire" (specifically, a greek goddess, see below) 
>  "Eris" = Greek goddess of strife (strife can lead to or cause "ire", coming before or after it) 
>  "ire" = anger 
>  "rise" = move from "sir" to "sire", or to go up

etc.

Comment: Darn was just about to enter this

Comment: Yeah, got the answer quickly, but even with it I still don't fully get the third line. Any ideas?

Comment: @Timoris I'll give you a hint in another set of letters r13(z < x < t)