# Monoalphabetic Geometry

Tags: word, cipher, rebus, language, letters

<sub>This is a second puzzle from the Monoalphabetic Equation series, you can check out the previous one [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75798/monoalphabetic-equation).</sub>

---

A set of letters has been replaced by $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ and one symbol has been replaced by $x$.
Following are some of the English words that consist of those letters, and their meaning:

> $abcd = \large ○ \normalsize + ▿\ + $ [image]
>
> $cbad = \large ● \normalsize + \small ○ $
>
> $cbda = \text{△} \normalsize +\ —\ +\ –\ $
>
> $cab \normalsize + x = x\ +$ \

**- What are the letters that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ replace, respectively?**
**- What is the symbol that $x$ replace?**

> [Here's a picture, in case the unicode is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGec.png)

Comment: Are the open circles in the first and second lines different sizes?

Comment: Yes, the (open) circle in the second line is a small circle.

Comment: So do the shapes on the right come out to be the definition of the word on the left?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer:

> $a$ = **r**, $b$ = **i**, $c$ = **t**, $d$ = **e**, $x$ = $∠$
>  Note: The shapes on the right are combined to make a symbol representing the word on the left.

$abcd = \large ○ \normalsize + ▿\ + $ [image: upward arrowhead]

> Word = **rite**
>  Depiction = Masonic ritual [symbol](http://www.cuttingedge.org/Masonic_Emblem_Encircled_Seattle.gif) (per @Timoris) or Wicca ritual [pentacle](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dresdenfiles/images/b/b7/Pentacle_2.png/revision/latest?cb=20170709153523), triangle + arrowhead make a star (intended answer per @Chrone)

$cbad = \large ● \normalsize + \small ○ $

> Word = **tire**
>  Depiction = [tire image](http://pngimg.com/uploads/tire/tire_PNG64.png)

$cbda = \text{△} \normalsize +\ —\ +\ –\ $

> Word = **tier**
>  Depiction = (per @Timoris) [tier image](https://peterlumpkins.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451a37369e2011570271a27970b-pi)

$cab \normalsize + x = x\ +$ \

> Okay, I found this one to be particularly clever:
>  $x$ is $∠$
>  thus $cab$ + $x$ = $x$ + \ becomes
>  **tri** $∠$ = $∠$ + \
>  or rather:
>  **triangle** = $△$

Comment: The last one is right under your nose. Although, I feel obligated to tell you that I should have use a pure symbol to replace the last one because it's not even a letter. I let it go because I thought that $x$ could pass off as a cross somehow, I guess not. It's entirely my fault. I'm sorry!

Comment: Oh. Alright, I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: So to speak, $x$ is one of the unicode symbols that is not a letter and I can assure you that it will become clear once you found out what it is!

Comment: That makes me instead think x is an rot13(natyr) character resulting in the last one being (gevnatyr) haha. My issue is I still don't understand how the shapes are used yet.

Comment: Try replace $x$ with rot13(natyr) unicode symbol and you will see the picture.

Comment: I think the first might be rot13(n serrznfba flzoby, gur bar jvgu gur pbzcnff) and the third is simply a rot13(gevnatyr jvgu gjb ubevmbagny yvarf fcyvggvat vg vagb 3 gvref).

Comment: Wow, good call on the first one @Timoris!

Comment: @Timoris It’s cool that you somehow connect it to r13(Znfbavp evghny flzoby) when I actually aimed for a simple r13(Jvppn evghny cragnpyr, gevnatyr + neebjurnq znxr n fgne). I’d say It’s good enough for me to accept. Also, you are right about third [one](https://peterlumpkins.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451a37369e2011570271a27970b-pi).

Comment: @Dorrulf It would be awesome if you reformat your answer after you got everything correct now! Also note that I've confirmed Timoris' answer as acceptable but also told them my intended answer and put up a link to the picture that depict what the third word is actually referring to.

Comment: Okay, will take care of that just a sec.